# Combine of a square and a parallelogram with GraphicsRow

Tags: graphics

```
g1 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], Rectangle[]}, 
   ImageSize -> {400, 400}];

g2 = Graphics[{{EdgeForm[{Dashed, Blue}], FaceForm[], Rectangle[]}, 
    GeometricTransformation[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
      Rectangle[]}, ShearingMatrix[30 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]}, 
   ImageSize -> {400, 400}];
```

But when I use `GraphicsRow` or `Grid` the two graphs appear with different sizing:

```
GraphicsRow[{g1, g2}]

Grid[{g1, g2}]
```

I guess this is trivial but I cannot find a way so that the two graphs appear with the same size.

PS.
Actually I want to replicate in Mathematica the following figure starting from scratch.

[image]

Comment: do you get what you need if you add the option `AspectRatio -> 1`  to `g1` and `g2`?

Comment: @kglr No. The squate appears as a rectangle now.

Comment: @kglr I tried to clarify my question. See the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[arrowAxes, annotatedArrow]
arrowAxes[lbl_, lngth_: 1/2, asize_: Large, off_: {20, -15}] := 
  {Arrowheads[asize], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, lngth}}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {lngth, 0}}], 
   Text[lbl[[1]], Offset[off, {0, lngth}]], 
   Text[lbl[[2]], Offset[Reverse[off], {lngth, 0}]]}

annotatedArrow[lbls_, fromto_: {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, size_: .025] := 
 Module[{ends = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1/5], 
      Line[{{-1, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/2}}], Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}], 
   labels = Graphics[{Text[Framed[#, FrameStyle -> None, Background -> White], 
      {0, 0}, Center]}] & /@ lbls}, 
  {Arrowheads[{{-size, 0, ends},
      ## & @@ Thread[{size, Subdivide[1 + Length@lbls][[2 ;; -2]], labels}], 
    {size, 1, ends}}], Arrow[fromto]}]
```

**Examples:**

```
isa = {300, 300};
isb = ShearingTransform[30 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}][isa];
pnt = ShearingTransform[30 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}][{0, 1}];
ga = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], Rectangle[], 
    arrowAxes[Style[Subscript[e, #], 18, Bold] & /@ {1, 2}]}, 
   ImageSize -> isa, ImagePadding -> 25];
gb = Graphics[{{EdgeForm[{Dashed, Blue}], FaceForm[], Rectangle[]}, 
    GeometricTransformation[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
      Rectangle[]}, ShearingMatrix[30 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]], 
    arrowAxes[Style[Subscript[e, #], 18, Bold] & /@ {1, 2}],
    Gray, AbsoluteThickness[1/5], 
    annotatedArrow[{Style[h, 18, Italic]}, Offset[{-20, 0}, #] & /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
    annotatedArrow[{Style[γ h, 18, Italic]}, Offset[{0, 20}, #] & /@ {{0, pnt[[2]]}, pnt}]},
   ImageSize -> isb, ImagePadding -> 25];

GraphicsRow[{ga, gb}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[{{ga, gb}}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Use `ShearingTransform[30 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}][{400, 400}]` as the image size for `g2` and add the option `PlotRangePadding -> None` to `g1` and `g2`:

```
g1 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], Rectangle[]}, 
   ImageSize -> {400, 400}, PlotRangePadding -> None];
g2 = Graphics[{{EdgeForm[{Dashed, Blue}], FaceForm[], Rectangle[]}, 
    GeometricTransformation[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
      Rectangle[]}, ShearingMatrix[30 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]}, 
   ImageSize -> ShearingTransform[30 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}][{400, 400}], 
   PlotRangePadding -> None];

GraphicsRow[{g1, g2}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[{{g1, g2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Not so trivial I think:-)!

Comment: @dimitris, you are welcome. Not trivial at all:)

Comment: Can you suggest me ways to include in the figures the annotated arrow, the unit vectors (arrows) and the texts or should I open a new thread?

Comment: @dimitris, thank you for the accept. I think unit vectors would not be difficult (I will post an update). I don't know an easy way to find the  correct image size for `g2` when texts are added.

Comment: Thanks again for your time!